# What does "farà molta strada" mean?

Tags: meaning, translation, idioms

I was reading comments on YouTube about the song [Odio le favole](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UKbzSCskhTQ), and I did not understand what is meant by the phrase "farà molta strada". For context, the full comment:

> Siamo felici che la canzone e il video vi piaccia; ci abbiamo lavorato molto e sono sicuro che Ermal farà molta strada!

My understanding of that is roughly: "We are happy you liked the song and video; We worked a lot and I am sure Ermal will do ...".

What is confusing to me is the use of the word strada, which must mean something other than street in this context. Could someone explain how it is used in this phrase?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

***[Fare strada](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/S/strada.shtml)*** is an idiomatic expression which is used figuratively to suggest that you will be successful, especially in your professional activities.

> - Progredire, diventare più importante. Vale per la carriera, il successo, la vita in generale.

(Hoepli)

Ermal farà molta strada, avrà successo nel propio lavoro.

Comment: Grazie mille. Ho molte cose imparare.

Comment: +1; @Jimmy: *da imparare. Nota che in questo caso avresti anche potuto dire "ho molta strada da fare". :D